# GRUB on my OS X (Hackintosh) disk after uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, macosx

I have a Hackintosh with 3 SSDs, each with a different OS on it (OS X 10.10, Windows 7, Ubuntu 14).

The problem is that I originally tried installing Ubuntu on the same SSD as the OS X drive AND I installed the boot loader at the root folder.

It would initially boot straight into Ubuntu when selecting the SSD (with both OS X and Ubuntu on it) so I deleted the Ubuntu partition.

Now when booting into the OS X disk, it goes into grub rescue (likely looking for the Ubuntu install that I deleted).

I tried installing different boot loaders such as Chimera, Chameleon, and Clover but none have overwritten GRUB and I am only able to boot into OS X when using my Unibeast USB.

How can I remove GRUB from my OS X drive?